# How soon before my visa expires can I travel?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, denial-of-entry, visa-expiration

My UK visa expires on January 28, 2018. Can I visit the UK from December 11, 2017 to January 5, 2018? Will I be turned away?

Answer (score 3):

**You can visit until the last day. That is what the validity dates are for!**

Many countries give visas of a certain length to cover changes of plans but there is no reason that you can't use the entirety of the visa subject to the maximum duration *per stay* which is often shorter than the validity of the visa.

Comment: Correct- But if you arrive on the last days of the validity period, be prepared for extra scrutiny about your plans to leave on time.

Answer (score 1):

It is good till the last day. Longer if you get hit by a car, Typhoon hits or such were you can not leave.